# trying to convert and transform a JSON source document to XML in XSLT

Tags: xslt-2.0, xslt-3.0

Following this run through

https://www.saxonica.com/papers/xmlprague-2016mhk.pdf

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet 
  xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
  xmlns:math="http://www.w3.org/2005/xpath-functions/math"
  xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
  xpath-default-namespace="http://www.w3.org/2005/xpath-functions"
  exclude-result-prefixes="xs math" version="3.0">

 <xsl:mode on-no-match="shallow-copy"/>

 <xsl:param name="input"/>

 <xsl:output method="text"/>

 <xsl:template name="xsl:initial-template">
    <xsl:variable name="input-as-xml" select="json-to-xml(unparsedtext($input))"/>
    <xsl:variable name="transformed-xml" as="document-node()">
       <xsl:apply-templates select="$input-as-xml"/>
    </xsl:variable>
    <xsl:value-of select="xml-to-json($transformed-xml)"/>
 </xsl:template>

 <xsl:template match="map[array[@key='tags']/string='ice']/number[@key='price']/text()">
    <xsl:value-of select="xs:decimal(.)*1.1"/>
 </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

I can make this work by passing the name of the JSON file through in the parameter 'input',
BUT
my infrastructure doesnt allow me to do this, it will try to transform inputs as source documents, is there a way to make this template use the source document (and not a param) without choking on it?

Comment: Is that Saxon 11 or 12? How do you run the transformation, from the console or from an API, or what kind of infrastructure do you use/have? As the input is parsed as plain text, what kind of "inputs as source documents" do you have in mind exactly, as plain text is not an XDM sequence, you can have nodes for XML documents or maps/arrays for JSON (processed as JSON/XDM maps/arrays), but plain text as the input source is kind of beyond the scope of XSLT.

Comment: saxon 11 probably he...you can basically set an XSLT thats triggered when a file turns up, passing the filename to the XSLT as the input doc....currently the input doc is always XML, but I was hoping to use the same infrastructure for JSON

Comment: Saxon 11 (all editions) can process JSON as the input, on the command line as `-json:file.json`, in the s9api by using JsonBuilder (I think). So while JSON can be processed as an input data type/sequence type (although not the way your shown XSLT works), I doubt that an infrastructure taking XML input is (magically?) able to use `-json` instead of `-s` or to use `JsonBuilder` instead of `DocumentBuilder` under the hood. Of course it all depends on who builds the "infrastructure".

Answer (score 1):

There is code in that article that processes JSON as XDM maps/arrays, if I collect the snippets then I (hope to correctly) end up with e.g.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
  version="3.0"
  xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
  xmlns:map="http://www.w3.org/2005/xpath-functions/map"
  xmlns:array="http://www.w3.org/2005/xpath-functions/array"
  exclude-result-prefixes="#all">
  
<xsl:template match=".[. instance of map(*)]" mode="#all">
 <xsl:choose>
 <xsl:when test="map:size(.) le 1">
 <xsl:sequence select="."/>
 </xsl:when>
 <xsl:otherwise>
 <xsl:map>
 <xsl:variable name="entries" as="map(*)*"
 select="map:for-each(., function($k, $v) { map:entry($k, $v) })"/>
 <xsl:apply-templates select="$entries" mode="#current"/>
 </xsl:map>
 </xsl:otherwise>
 </xsl:choose>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match=".[. instance of array(*)]" mode="#all">
 <xsl:choose>
 <xsl:when test="array:size(.) = 0">
 <xsl:sequence select="[]"/>
 </xsl:when>
 <xsl:otherwise>
 <xsl:variable name="head" as="item()*">
 <xsl:apply-templates select="array:head(.)" mode="#current"/>
 </xsl:variable>
 <xsl:variable name="tail" as="array(*)">
 <xsl:apply-templates select="array:tail(.)" mode="#current"/>
 </xsl:variable>
 <xsl:sequence select="array:join((array{$head}, $tail))"/>
 </xsl:otherwise>
 </xsl:choose>
 </xsl:template>

  <xsl:mode on-no-match="shallow-copy" on-multiple-match="use-last"/>
  
  <xsl:output method="json" indent="yes"/>

<xsl:template match=".[. instance of map(*)][?tags = 'ice']">
 <xsl:map>
    <xsl:sequence select="map:for-each(., function($k, $v){ map{$k : if ($k = 'price') then $v*1.1 else $v }})"/>
 </xsl:map>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

For such an XSLT stylesheet you could pass in the sample JSON from the article as e.g. `-json:file.json` to Saxon 11 or 12 on the command line or using the API by parsing the JSON with JsonBuilder of the s9api.

An "infrastructure" allowing you to indicate what kind of input you have and using s9api is my XML workbench; an example is [here](https://martin-honnen.github.io/xml-workbench/?code=%3C%3Fxml%20version%3D%221.0%22%20encoding%3D%22utf-8%22%3F%3E%0A%3Cxsl%3Astylesheet%20xmlns%3Axsl%3D%22http%3A%2F%2Fwww.w3.org%2F1999%2FXSL%2FTransform%22%0A%20%20version%3D%223.0%22%0A%20%20xmlns%3Axs%3D%22http%3A%2F%2Fwww.w3.org%2F2001%2FXMLSchema%22%0A%20%20xmlns%3Amap%3D%22http%3A%2F%2Fwww.w3.org%2F2005%2Fxpath-functions%2Fmap%22%0A%20%20xmlns%3Aarray%3D%22http%3A%2F%2Fwww.w3.org%2F2005%2Fxpath-functions%2Farray%22%0A%20%20exclude-result-prefixes%3D%22%23all%22%3E%0A%20%20%0A%3Cxsl%3Atemplate%20match%3D%22.%5B.%20instance%20of%20map%28*%29%5D%22%20mode%3D%22%23all%22%3E%0A%20%3Cxsl%3Achoose%3E%0A%20%3Cxsl%3Awhen%20test%3D%22map%3Asize%28.%29%20le%201%22%3E%0A%20%3Cxsl%3Asequence%20select%3D%22.%22%2F%3E%0A%20%3C%2Fxsl%3Awhen%3E%0A%20%3Cxsl%3Aotherwise%3E%0A%20%3Cxsl%3Amap%3E%0A%20%3Cxsl%3Avariable%20name%3D%22entries%22%20as%3D%22map%28*%29*%22%0A%20select%3D%22map%3Afor-each%28.%2C%20function%28%24k%2C%20%24v%29%20%7B%20map%3Aentry%28%24k%2C%20%24v%29%20%7D%29%22%2F%3E%0A%20%3Cxsl%3Aapply-templates%20select%3D%22%24entries%22%20mode%3D%22%23current%22%2F%3E%0A%20%3C%2Fxsl%3Amap%3E%0A%20%3C%2Fxsl%3Aotherwise%3E%0A%20%3C%2Fxsl%3Achoose%3E%0A%3C%2Fxsl%3Atemplate%3E%0A%0A%3Cxsl%3Atemplate%20match%3D%22.%5B.%20instance%20of%20array%28*%29%5D%22%20mode%3D%22%23all%22%3E%0A%20%3Cxsl%3Achoose%3E%0A%20%3Cxsl%3Awhen%20test%3D%22array%3Asize%28.%29%20%3D%200%22%3E%0A%20%3Cxsl%3Asequence%20select%3D%22%5B%5D%22%2F%3E%0A%20%3C%2Fxsl%3Awhen%3E%0A%20%3Cxsl%3Aotherwise%3E%0A%20%3Cxsl%3Avariable%20name%3D%22head%22%20as%3D%22item%28%29*%22%3E%0A%20%3Cxsl%3Aapply-templates%20select%3D%22array%3Ahead%28.%29%22%20mode%3D%22%23current%22%2F%3E%0A%20%3C%2Fxsl%3Avariable%3E%0A%20%3Cxsl%3Avariable%20name%3D%22tail%22%20as%3D%22array%28*%29%22%3E%0A%20%3Cxsl%3Aapply-templates%20select%3D%22array%3Atail%28.%29%22%20mode%3D%22%23current%22%2F%3E%0A%20%3C%2Fxsl%3Avariable%3E%0A%20%3Cxsl%3Asequence%20select%3D%22array%3Ajoin%28%28array%7B%24head%7D%2C%20%24tail%29%29%22%2F%3E%0A%20%3C%2Fxsl%3Aotherwise%3E%0A%20%3C%2Fxsl%3Achoose%3E%0A%20%3C%2Fxsl%3Atemplate%3E%0A%0A%20%20%3Cxsl%3Amode%20on-no-match%3D%22shallow-copy%22%20on-multiple-match%3D%22use-last%22%2F%3E%0A%20%20%0A%20%20%3Cxsl%3Aoutput%20method%3D%22json%22%20indent%3D%22yes%22%2F%3E%0A%0A%3Cxsl%3Atemplate%20match%3D%22.%5B.%20instance%20of%20map%28*%29%5D%5B%3Ftags%20%3D%20%27ice%27%5D%22%3E%0A%20%3Cxsl%3Amap%3E%0A%20%20%20%20%3Cxsl%3Asequence%20select%3D%22map%3Afor-each%28.%2C%20function%28%24k%2C%20%24v%29%7B%20map%7B%24k%20%3A%20if%20%28%24k%20%3D%20%27price%27%29%20then%20%24v*1.1%20else%20%24v%20%7D%7D%29%22%2F%3E%0A%20%3C%2Fxsl%3Amap%3E%0A%3C%2Fxsl%3Atemplate%3E%0A%0A%0A%0A%3C%2Fxsl%3Astylesheet%3E%0A&input=%5B%0D%0A%20%7B%0D%0A%20%22id%22%3A%202%2C%0D%0A%20%22name%22%3A%20%22An%20ice%20sculpture%22%2C%0D%0A%20%22price%22%3A%2012.50%2C%0D%0A%20%22tags%22%3A%20%5B%22cold%22%2C%20%22ice%22%5D%2C%0D%0A%20%22dimensions%22%3A%20%7B%0D%0A%20%22length%22%3A%207.0%2C%0D%0A%20%22width%22%3A%2012.0%2C%0D%0A%20%22height%22%3A%209.5%0D%0A%20%7D%2C%0D%0A%20%22warehouseLocation%22%3A%20%7B%0D%0A%20%22latitude%22%3A%20-78.75%2C%0D%0A%20%22longitude%22%3A%2020.4%0D%0A%20%7D%0D%0A%20%7D%2C%0D%0A%20%7B%0D%0A%20%22id%22%3A%203%2C%0D%0A%20%22name%22%3A%20%22A%20blue%20mouse%22%2C%0D%0A%20%22price%22%3A%2025.50%2C%0D%0A%20%22dimensions%22%3A%20%7B%0D%0A%20%22length%22%3A%203.1%2C%0D%0A%20%22width%22%3A%201.0%2C%0D%0A%20%22height%22%3A%201.0%0D%0A%20%7D%2C%0D%0A%20%22warehouseLocation%22%3A%20%7B%0D%0A%20%22latitude%22%3A%2054.4%2C%0D%0A%20%22longitude%22%3A%20-32.7%0D%0A%20%7D%0D%0A%20%7D%0D%0A%5D%0D%0A&code-type=XSLT&input-type=JSON). But even there you have to select whether you have XML input or JSON input, to allow the code to decide whether DocumentBuilder or JsonBuilder is used.

Comment: ah, so this requires changing the way the XSLT engine is triggered. There is no <xsl:input> like instruction to simply instruct the template how to parse the input?

Comment: "The input" used to be XML, in XSLT 3 it can also be JSON but I think at least Saxon Java and CS need the user to indicate/select with either `-s:file.xml` or `-json:file.xml` what the primary input is. Of course for secondary inputs in addition to `doc('file.xml')` you now have `json-doc('file.json')`. I think SaxonJS has an API where the primary input is provided the same way for XML and JSON but you need to indicate with an additional flag if it is JSON.

Comment: It is not really the call of the XSLT engine/processor that changes, that will be e.g. `applyTemplates` with s9api, it is simply that parsing of the input for XML is done with an XML parser (exposed in the API as `DocumentBuilder`) and for JSON with a JSON parser (exposed in the API as JsonBuilder).

Comment: in a functional sense its changing, there is effectively a single function that takes an xslt file and an input file, you are saying that if the input file is an xml that function needs to tell saxon to parse it as xml and if its json, it needs to parse it as json? currently it parses it as XML, I was hoping that Saxon would do something special and detect the file (which is an awful ideal) or I would be able to instruct the engine from INSIDE the stylesheet how to parse the input, i.e. I think im dead in the water, without changing the infrastructure.

Comment: As I said, the closest is SaxonJS in its `SaxonJS.transform` JavaScript API https://www.saxonica.com/saxon-js/documentation2/index.html#!api/transform expecting a "sourceLocation: URI that can be used to locate the XML or JSON document." but even there you need to set `sourceType` as `json`, it defaults to `xml`.